# Angular4 - Bootstrap Line Tabs

Tags: css, angular

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/bootstrap-line-tabs-by-keenthemes

I'm new to Angular and so my work has set me a beginner's challenge to modify their basic navbar menu.

I've chosen the menu in the link provided. However, the difference with my menu is that the pages linked are separate HTML files which Angular displays 
in the router-outlet below.

When you click a tab the correct page displays but the active tab does not change (the first tab remains highlighted.)

Is this problem caused by my lack of knowledge of Angular or CSS??
Is it possible to get the navbar properly working within this Angular environment?
All feedback much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's really difficult to understand what's going on without being able to see the code in action. Consider providing a [mcve] to help us help you.

Comment: https://codepen.io/jamesbcn/pen/weYdPw Please see link for demonstration of the issue.

Comment: If you place an external link on a tab navigation link it will stop being a tab navigation link. It will be a normal link, taking you to whatever `URL` your placed in `href`. You're not displaying/loading content inside your current page, but rather going to a different new page. Use tabs when you want to remain in the current page. Note you can use the tab change event to load content and make ajax calls if you need to. However placing external `href`s on tab navigation is not the way to go. Also, the pen you posted has nothing to do with Angular. Example should be Complete and Verifiable.

Comment: Yeah, the pen was an attempt to make a simplified example. In Angular, the new html page is displayed in the router-outlet below. Would a link to chat.html or contact.html still be classed as an external link in Angular (even though it's being displayed on the same page)?

Comment: Yes, it's basically a "new" page from the browser's point of view (your app's router provides an entry in the history of the browser and so on...). Tabs are for inline display of content, usually all loaded at page load. You could tweak them and fire some async loads of content on change tab event but that would be an exception, not the rule. Just use a normal navigation and style it as tabs if that's what you need. place an `active` class on the current navigation item, based on current view.

Comment: there is no nav html in the 3 tab webpages though. the nav html is situated only in the app.component.html file (and the css in app.component.css)... chat.html and the rest only have container html